# can't access objects created with class __init__ function :

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python so please pardon me if this is trivial, but I couldn't find any answer so far. Why do I get this error message?

```
#define a class containing a variable and a method
#automatically generate n instances called AA,BB, CC each containing as 
#variable the letter's number (a=1, b=2 etc.)
#define a function returning "my name is BB and my var is 2"

n=5
class Letters(object):
    def __init__(self, name, var):
        self.var=var
        self.name = name
    def hello(self):
        print('my name is %s and my var is %d'%(self.name, self.var))
for x in range(0,n):
    y=chr(x+97).upper()*2
    y=Letters(y,x+1)
    y.hello()
print(BB.var)
```

And I get this output, which suggests the objects have been created, yet I can't access to the BB object and its var...

```
my name is AA and my var is 1
my name is BB and my var is 2
my name is CC and my var is 3
my name is DD and my var is 4
my name is EE and my var is 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-600f444742c0> in <module>()
     13     y=Letters(y,x+1)
     14     y.hello()
---> 15 print(BB.var)

NameError: name 'BB' is not defined
```

Any explanation?

Comment: Yes. There is no variable named `BB`. One of your `Letter` objects has a `name` attribute which is assigned to the *string* `"BB"`, but that is neither here nor there...

Comment: The fact the the instance has a `name` attribute with the value `'BB'` does **not** mean that the identifier `BB` exists or is a reference to that instance. I'd recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I think the downvotes are overly harsh. The question itself is much better quality than your typical first question - it provides a small, self-contained example that reproduces the problem and provides the error-message and stack-trace.

Comment: Minor point of style advice: if your range starts at 0 you don't need to put in two arguments. You can just do `range(n)` here.

Comment: Thank you for all comments, really useful, I'm reading the nedbatchelder article. Thanks also for being understanding for my first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to set a global variable. You can do this using `globals()`, like:

```
globals()["AA"] = Letters("AA", 3)
```

So you can do this:

```
for x in range(n):
    name= chr(x + 97).upper() * 2
    globals()[name] = Letters(name, x + 1)

AA.hello()
print(BB.var)
```

Comment: This works, thanks very much. 
In the `for` loop, I had to change the following line as well to  `globals()[name].hello()` 
Also: does creating this global variable only mean it is accessible from anywhere in the code, or that it is located elsewhere than in the objects i am creating? If this question doesn't make sense: does class objects simply concatenate a certain set of methods and variables without being "located" within a class - only fulfilling the formal requirements of the class? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

1. Each of the `Letters` objects goes away at the next iteration of your loop. `y` is a new `Letters` object with new `name` and `var` -- the `y` from prior iterations is gone forever. If you want to keep each object you create you'll need to use a collection like a list or dict.
2. At the end, `print(BB.var)` is trying to print a variable called `BB`, or more specifically its `var` attribute. But you've never created a variable with that name, which is what `NameError: name 'BB' is not defined` is telling you.

You could do something like this instead:

```
l = [] # new empty list
for x in range(0,n):
    y=chr(x+97).upper()*2
    y=Letters(y,x+1)
    y.hello()
    l.append(y) # add (append) y to the end of l
print(l[1].var) # print 2nd item's `var` which is BB
```

Comment: 1)Makes sense. I was slightly confused because I thought the objects would be referred by the string `y`was pointing at, that means, at each iteration, AA, BB etc. - thus at each iteration the previous object wouldn't go away.
2) Is this procedure equivalent to the one given by Zweedend `globals()[name]`in the sense that the list you created is within the global symbol table?